# Is there a specific site to ask about recycling railroads at SE?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I seem to remember having asked or commented on questions related to railroads.  But now that I have one, I cannot find a pertinent stack using "train" or "rail" or "railroad" nor the plurals of those.

This is obviously not the place to ask the question, but it regards the recycling (or lack thereof) of rails and spikes.

Comment: Please clarify what specific relatation of your question would be regarding _railroads_, _trains_ or _rail_. That's a pretty broad field.

Comment: Yes, it is a pretty broad field.  But I am not asking a railroad question here where it doesn't belong.  I am asking where to find the stack it belongs in if such exists.

Comment: I well understood that.

Comment: Well, the rails and spikes should be just recycled as iron or steel, unless the spikes were made of gold (common for famous milestones at railroads).

Comment: They should be, but they aren't.

Answer (score 11):

> **Is there a specific site to ask about recycling railroads at SE?**

**No there isn't.**

> This is obviously not the place to ask the question, but it regards the recycling (or lack thereof) of rails and spikes.

While that site doesn't have particular tags to specify your field, that's probably best asked at

- [SE Sustainable Living](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upcycling)

which is specifically designed to ask questions about recycling and upcycling.

Comment: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/9844/why-isn-t-railroad-steel-recycled